# Flutter Align widget rect does not detect the onTap gesture

Tags: layout, gesture, flutter

I have a couple of image buttons laid out as follows :

[image]

The layout code is :

```
new Container(
  height: 48.0,
  child: new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new GestureDetector(
        onTap: cancelTurn,
        child: new Align(child: new Image.asset("assets/cancel_button.png"), widthFactor: 1.5),
      ),
      new Expanded(child: new Container()),
      new GestureDetector(
        onTap: confirmTurn,
        child: new Align(child: new Image.asset("assets/confirm_button.png"), widthFactor: 1.5),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

I am using `Align` widget to hopefully increase the clickable area of the `GestureDetector`. However, my clicks only work when I click inside the `Image` widget rect. If you notice, the bounds/rects for `Align` and `Image` are different. `Align` is extended beyond the `Image` child by using the `widthFactor` property (set to `1.5`)

Any ideas on why the `Align` widget might not be detecting the tap gesture in its bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing a `hitTestBehavior` of [`HitTestBehavior.opaque`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) to the `GestureDetector`.

Other tips:

- Instead of `Align`, consider a [`Padding`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html).
- Consider using an [`IconButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) with [`Icons.close`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Icons/close-constant.html) and [`Icons.check`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Icons/check-constant.html) instead of embedding a custom png. You could wrap it in a [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) to draw the black circle and it will even clip the ink splash for you automatically.

Comment: passing `behavior` of `HitTestBehavior.opaque` works. Thanks! PS. Don't want to use padding because I want the rect to take up as much vertical space as available.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired effect, you could replace the `GestureDetector` elements for `InkWell`. This will give a feedback to the user (due to the Ink animation) and will be activated when the whole area is pressed.

To do that, your container should look like this:

```
   new Container(
      height: 48.0,
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new InkWell(
            onTap: cancelTurn,
            child: new Align(child: new Image.asset("assets/cancel_button.png"), widthFactor: 1.5),
          ),
          new Expanded(child: new Container()),
          new InkWell(
            onTap: confirmTurn,
            child: new Align(child: new Image.asset("assets/confirm_button.png"), widthFactor: 1.5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I think it will look weird to have a rectangular ink splash for a circular button.